# Where is the edit widget for photos in QGIS3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis2web

I’d like to use qgis2web to display a photo when you click on a polygon in the map using qgis2web, but I can’t seem to find the correct settings.

I have a table with a column named photos. Each row has a field with a html link to an image. I’ve read that in version 2.8 you would simply choose “photo” in the field edit widget, but there is not a photo option in QGIS 3. The replacement method appears to be the “Attachment” option in the Attributes Form in the Layer Properties.

I have tried every combination I can think of and still can’t get it to work. The closest I have come is an html link that when clicked on, would open another window to display the image.

Using QGIS version 3.0.1-Girona and the latest plugin update for qgis2web

Can anyone let me in on the secret to making this work?

Answer (score 2):

Well I’m embarrassed to say that my problem was a typo that I copied from test to test to test. Qgis2Web recognizes an url and works flawlessly without any setting at all. Assuming you don’t have a typo….